# How to acceptance test captcha-protected web application functionality?

Tags: selenium, captcha, pyramid, recaptcha, acceptance-testing

I would like to add a captcha, such as reCaptcha, to a certain functionality on my site. How could I adapt my acceptance tests?

Is the only solution to disable the captcha's on the staging site?

Clarification:

Of course I am not speaking of brute-force cracking my own captcha, but e.g. some option to inject a state into the captcha from the server side that my test knows about.

PS My server side code uses the Pyramid framework, and my tests are written using Selenium

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point isn't to test Captcha with your Selenium tests -- Why spend the significant effort to test a third party tool?

Instead, I'd have a Selenium test that verifies your Captcha is showing up. This validates your Captcha is present and active. After that test I'd turn Captcha off and proceed with your other validation tests. I'd also have a final step of turning Captcha back on and repeating the test detecting Captcha is active. That way you're ensuring you didn't miss something when reactivating Captcha.

Comment: I like this approach better than disabling captcha's alltogether, since I can rely on my acceptance tests to ensure that the captcha's are up. However I'm not sure how to implement this yet. Restart and reconfigure the app in between tests?

Comment: Yes, you'd need a step between your tests to toggle the Captcha off. I'm not familiar enough with that platform to say if you'd need to restart your app or not. Obviously you'd need the opposite action of enabling and possibly restarting as you're finishing up your test pass.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the only option is disabling Captcha - for a very good reason. If it's easy enough to bypass it with Selenium, why would you have a Captcha in the first place?

Comment: Right now my staging is an exact copy of production. I am afraid that if I add some logic that detects whether we are on staging or production, I run into risks. What if the attacker succeeds at making my site think its on staging? All captcha's would be gone.

Comment: +1 for disabling during selenium tests. I usually have a config file for acceptance and a config file for production. This is where I would put a config param, for `captcha = true/false`

Comment: @JaspervandenBosch You are correct, but if an attacker can do that, worrying about CAPTCHA's being disabled is the least of your worries. It is perfectly logical and reasonable to have code in to detect what environment you are running against.

Comment: This would be a motivation for staging.ini versus production.ini where one of them has (as Antoine suggested) `captcha = false`.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the CAPTCHA by using a test code in the input box. If the captcha fails but matches the test code, continue.