# Testing Amazon.in using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using testNG framework to automate test cases for testing of amazon.in.
However when the script tries to login, site displays the following message along with a captcha -

> To better protect your account, please re-enter your password and then enter the characters as they are shown in the image below.

Is there any workaround this problem?

Comment: You set up a [test environment without the CAPTCHA](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/17022/how-to-fill-captcha-using-automation), because the point of CAPTCHA is to guard against automation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to acceptance test captcha-protected web application functionality?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373434/how-to-acceptance-test-captcha-protected-web-application-functionality)